# Generate test data in Raven DB

Tags: ravendb, seed, test-data

I am looking for a preferred and maintainable way of test data generation in Raven DB. Currently, our team does have a way to do it through .NET code. Example is provided.

However, i am looking for different options. Please share.

```
public void Execute()
        {
            using (var documentStore = new DocumentStore { ConnectionStringName = "RavenDb" })
            {
                documentStore.Conventions.DefaultQueryingConsistency = ConsistencyOptions.QueryYourWrites;

                // Override the default key prefix generation strategy of Pascal case to lower case.
                documentStore.Conventions.FindTypeTagName = type => DocumentConvention.DefaultTypeTagName(type).ToLower();

                documentStore.Initialize();

                InitializeData(documentStore);
            }
        }
```

**Edit:** [Raven-overflow](https://github.com/PureKrome/RavenOverflow) is really helpful. Thanks for pointing out to the right place.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try checking out [RavenOverflow](https://github.com/PureKrome/RavenOverflow). In there, I've got a [FakeData](https://github.com/PureKrome/RavenOverflow/tree/master/Code/RavenOverflow.FakeData) project that has fake data (both hardcoded AND randomly generated). This can then be used in either my [Tests](https://github.com/PureKrome/RavenOverflow/tree/master/Code/RavenOverflow.Tests) project or the [Main Website](https://github.com/PureKrome/RavenOverflow/tree/master/Code/RavenOverflow.Web) :)

Here's some sample code...

```
if (isDataToBeSeeded)
{
    HelperUtilities.CreateSeedData(documentStore);
}
```

....

```
public static void CreateSeedData(IDocumentStore documentStore)
{
    Condition.Requires(documentStore).IsNotNull();

    using (IDocumentSession documentSession = documentStore.OpenSession())
    {
        // First, check to make sure we don't have any data.
        var user = documentSession.Load<User>(1);
        if (user != null)
        {
            // ooOooo! we have a user, so it's assumed we actually have some seeded data.
            return;
        }

        // We have no users, so it's assumed we therefore have no data at all.
        // So let's fake some up :)

        // Users.
        ICollection<User> users = FakeUsers.CreateFakeUsers(50);
        StoreFakeEntities(users, documentSession);

        // Questions.
        ICollection<Question> questions = FakeQuestions.CreateFakeQuestions(users.Select(x => x.Id).ToList());
        StoreFakeEntities(questions, documentSession);

        documentSession.SaveChanges();

        // Make sure all our indexes are not stale.
        documentStore.WaitForStaleIndexesToComplete();
    }
}
```

....

```
public static ICollection<Question> CreateFakeQuestions(IList<string> userIds, int numberOfFakeQuestions)
{
.... you get the idea .....
}
```